# Unhiding a list to make it searchable

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I have a list that was set to hidden on creation. I have used CSOM to set the hidden property to false - which works fine using the following code (for unhiding the list).

```
ClientContext ctx = DALSingleton.SharePointContext.CreateAppOnlyClientContextForSPHost();
List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(level.ListName);
list.Hidden = false;
list.Update();                
ctx.Load(list);
await ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

I've done this to make the list searchable - in which it can't be searched whilst hidden -
[Searching a hidden list in SharePoint](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/261171b0-d047-4e44-9c99-1eb4d2045fc5/cant-search-file-in-sharepoint-hidden-list)

My problem is that now that the list is visible I still can't search the list. Am I missing something? I have tried re-indexing the site and the list individually.

Is this a SharePoint limitation?

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is the value of the NoCrawl property?

Comment: @KasperBoLarsen NoCrawl Value is set to false in both hidden list and visible list by default